# CSS to rotate an image/icon(spinner) in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

Css to convert an icon/image into spinner
add following properties to the class of that icon/image

```
.spinner{
 -webkit-animation: load3 1.4s infinite linear;
 animation: load3 1.4s infinite linear;
 -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
 transform: translateZ(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your CSS and you'll have a rotating image

```
@keyframes load3 {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort. but my css is also working. i didn't use the right class name.

Comment: @ali-usmaan than what is the question?